# MySQLi query not working. Multiple AND statements

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to add an extra `AND` statement to my SQL query.
I work fine as:

```
SELECT * FROM tsv WHERE YEAR(`Reporting Date`) = 2017 AND MONTH(`Reporting Date`) = 6
```

But when I try to add the extra line (`AND ISRC = QZERG1727327`) in the end it dosen´t work any more

```
SELECT * FROM tsv WHERE YEAR(`Reporting Date`) = 2017 AND MONTH(`Reporting Date`) = 6 AND ISRC = QZERG1727327
```

It´s hard to find any solutions online, I really don´t know what to do.

Comment: you should show us the error message, and by the way, isn't ISRC string?

Comment: Is `ISRC` a string? Then `QZERG...` should be in single quotes.

Comment: @KarstenKoop `ISRC` is the row name :)

Comment: @zebnat I don´t get any errors

Comment: sure, but what's its type?

Comment: @KarstenKoop the type is text

Comment: Then try it with single quotes

Comment: You can use the first statment only then with php check if $row["ISRC"]==QZERG1727327 then add the row to array of result

Comment: @KarstenKoop still not working with " ` "

Comment: @Osama Actually I think that would be a way around it! Thanks! But I´m not feeling that it´s the right way to do it and it would probably have to load more than if I could sort it out in the query :)

Comment: that's a backtick, single quote would be `'` (btw. the apostrophes in your comments also look wrong)

Comment: @KarstenKoop OHH yes!! that did the trick :D thanks.. will you post this as an answer?

Comment: So only add a quote around ISRC value because it is a string

Comment: Thanks @Osama! but I´ve alrready sorted it out with Karsten :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in SQL have to be enclosed in single quotes, so your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM tsv 
WHERE YEAR(`Reporting Date`)=2017 AND MONTH(`Reporting Date`)=6 
  AND ISRC='QZERG1727327'
```